# ModalPopupExtender doesn't fire till after method is run

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

I have a modalpopupextender (mpe) that is supposed to pop up before a method runs.  It doesn't show up before it runs, it shows up *after* the method runs despite the code below: (note:  The "TestMethod" method is called by a button press event.)

```
Protected Void TestMethod()
{
   mpeDeleteServer.Show();
   UpdateAllServerInfo();  //Method
}
```

The method itself consists of (in a nutshell), getting data from a sql server database, doing a foreach loop through the datatable, and updating a gridview.
Alone the method works fine.  I want this mpe to show up, of course, to display some information.  Unfortunately it doesn't show up until ***AFTER*** the method has run.
Now if I comment out the method, the mpe shows right up, no issues.  If I unComment it, it won't show up till after the run.

I'll provide any more code if you need something specific.

Comment: Is the mpe a server control? bootstrap? What is it? Have you tried using OnClientClick in the markup? OnClientClick (front end) fires before Click (code behind).

Comment: It is not bootstrap, it's AJAX.  Code for it is below:

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeDeleteServer" runat="server" PopupControlID="idDeleteSvr" OkControlID="hdnDeleteField"
                                        TargetControlID="cmdHiddenDelete" BackgroundCssClass="modal_popup_bg" />

It is encapsulated within a <asp:UpdatePanel> as well.  Not sure if that info is needed or not but want to throw that in just in case.